# Can apps in Huawei AppGallery be downloaded in China?

Tags: google-play-store, huawei

I have published [a mobile game](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.quizjungle2.android) in Google Play Store. Apparently it cannot be played in China as China has banned Google. Huawei provides an alternative app store -- Huawei AppGallery. Does it mean that if I upload my game [there](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/), players from China will be able to download my game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through their publication process, I can answer the question now.

The answer is yes. They give you the option to publish apps in China, on the condition you submit [additional documents](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/30215) required by the government of China. You need also to display a Health Advice in your app prominently.

[image: screen shot 1]
[image]

Comment: Where can I get these documents?

Comment: I am afraid you have to get them from Chinese ministries through an agent working in China.

Comment: As far as I can tell, health advice is mandatory for games, not apps. Furthermore I was able to publish 2 apps today without providing any further documentation than the Huawei exemption.

Comment: @3c71 where can I get the Huawei exemption document?